# Docker mount volume on SELinux enabled server

Tags: docker, nginx, selinux

I'm trying to run Nginx as the docker container on SELinux enabled server with mounted configuration as

```
-v /host/path/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:Z
```

That works fine till I will deploy updated configuration using ansible playbook (user/group root and mode 0644) as:

```
  tasks:
    - name: remove NGINX conf
      file:
        path: "/host/path/nginx.conf"
        state: absent
      become: true

    - name: copy NGINX conf
      become: true
      copy:
        src: "../nginx-conf/nginx.conf"
        dest: "/host/path/nginx.conf"
        mode: 0640
        owner: root
        group: root
```

and then reload nginx in the container as

```
docker container exec nginx-service nginx -s reload
```

that will error out with Permission Denied (13) to deployed configuration.

When I will check permissions to `/host/path/nginx.conf` those are correct (user/group:root and mode 0644) but for some reason nginx is not able to read that file.

When I will get inside the container and check `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` permissions there are not carried over - they show up as question marks.

Any clue how to get it to work without reloading whole container just nginx service?

Comment: Deleting and recreating the container is pretty routine; it's not running anything besides nginx so there's no need to take special steps just to restart the one process.

Comment: @DavidMaze I was looking at start/stop rather than delete and recreate container. Also I'm using Nginx as the api gateway so in both cases I will need to train connections when service reload takes just not whole sec.